# Sporadically null Entity Framework Foreign keys using DbSet Find and Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

As the title says I'm having sporadically null entries in my code. I can't find any pattern since one cycle below can work when the code is ran one time and fail another time.

Code that fails:

```
var cycle = _dbContext.RenewalCycles.Find(businessSystemId, caseId, action, cycle);

var renewalDateEvent = cycle.CaseEvents?.FirstOrDefault(
   caseEvent => caseEvent.TPEvent.EventClassifications.Any(eventClassification => eventClassification.ClassificationId == Classifications.RenewalDueDate));
```

Models:

TPRenewalCycle:

```
public class TPRenewalCycle
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TPCase")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TPCase")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    public virtual TPCase TPCase { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    public int? Year { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string YearDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPCaseEvent> CaseEvents { get; set; }

}
```

TPCaseEvent:

```
public class TPCaseEvent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string BusinessSystemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("TPRenewalCycle")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Cycle { get; set; }

    public virtual TPRenewalCycle TPRenewalCycle { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 4)]
    [ForeignKey("TPEvent")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EventNo { get; set; }

    public virtual TPEvent TPEvent { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
}
```

TPEvent:

```
public class TPEvent
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EventNo { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string InternalName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ExternalName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
    [MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPEventClassification> EventClassifications { get; set; }
}
```

TPEventClassification:

```
public class TPEventClassification
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("TPClassification")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Classifications ClassificationId { get; set; }

    public virtual TPClassification TPClassification { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("TPEvent")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EventNo { get; set; }

    public virtual TPEvent TPEvent { get; set; }
}
```

TPClassification:

```
public class TPClassification
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Classifications ClassificationId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsCyclical { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(400)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TPEventClassification> EventClassifications { get; set; }
}
```

Null for TPEvent:

[image]

Exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And when it is ran a second time it is loaded via `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies`.

[image]

Why is this happening here? Do I need to skip using `Find` and instead load using `FirstOrDefault` with `Include` for TPEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same error with cases so I will show how I fixed it there. `Find` and `FirstOrDefault` like below both threw the same exception.

```
//Sporadic exceptions like above. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
var tpCase = _DbContext.Cases
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.BusinessSystemId == businessSystemId &&
                         x.CaseId == caseId);
```

However when I included everything in the query it worked:

```
var tpCase = _DbContext.Cases
    .Where(x => x.BusinessSystemId == businessSystemId &&
                x.CaseId == caseId)
    .Include(tpCase => tpCase.RenewalCycles.Select(renewalCycle => renewalCycle.CaseEvents.Select(caseEvent => caseEvent.TPEvent.EventClassifications)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```